# What is the "nice" way to debug django when requests originate remotely?

Tags: python, django, debugging

When someone is remotely hitting a Django server (say, not with a browser, but with a robot or other automated tool), what is the "nice" way for me to trace what the server is doing, and attempt to debug any problems?

Comment: Does it make a difference whether the user agent is a robot or a web browser?

Comment: Obviously `import logging` is your friend, but I suspect there's a particular problem you're trying to fix or a particular area you're trying to test - any clues?

Comment: Logging != debugging :P I would like to specifically debug the application - ie, arbitrarily enter debug mode in the middle of a call, step through code, observe how variables change, etc...

Comment: You can use `import pdb` than `pdb.set_trace()` to run the python debugger in console while using `./manage.py runserver`. Just put it in a line in which you want to start debugging. I don't think there's an easy way to do it on production server.

Comment: @Wojciech Żółtak your answer looks like the best option so far. I saw an alternative with server_plus (./manage.py runserver_plus) but that also doesn't seem appropriate for prod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What you should do

Debugging should not be done on a production server, so you should use a development server, where you can basically use `manage.py runserver`+ `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`.

### Why couldn't you do it

Say your dev server is running on a platform like heroku, you might not be able to control how your script is started. From there, using remote-debugging is possible, and here's how you could do it:

## What you could do

**If** you want to be able to step-in code execution and debug remotely (which is **totally** innapropriate for a production setup), you could use [`rpdb`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpdb/). I insist on the fact that you *shouldn't* be doing this unless you know what you're doing (and provided you're *not* doing it on a production server!)

Basically, what `rpdb`does is that when you call `rpdb.set_trace()`, `pdb` is started and its `stdin`and `stdout`are redirected towards port 4444 (but you can change that of course). You'd then telnet (or netcat, for that matter) to that port and do your debugging thing from there.

### Closing words

Really, you shouldn't be doing this.